# Gson Serialization of Map subclass that also has explicitly-defined properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, jsonserializer

I have a collection of generated java beans where each bean defines one or more fields, plus it subclasses `HashMap<String, T>` where `T` is a parameterised type. The generated fields model explicitly-defined schema properties within a `JSON schema`, and the subclassing of `HashMap` is done to support additional "*arbitrary*" properties of a specific type (specified by the JSON schema's "*additionalProperties*" field, for those that are familiar with JSON Schema).
Here is an example of a generated bean:

```
public class MyModel extends HashMap<String, Foo> {
    private String prop1;
    private Long prop2;

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp1(String value) {
        this.prop1 = value;
    }

    public Long getProp2() {
        return prop2;
    }

    public void setProp2(Long prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

In this example, the user can set `prop1` or `prop2` as normal bean properties and can also set arbitrary properties of type `Foo` via the `Map`'s `put()` method, where `Foo` is just some other user-defined type.

The problem is that, by default, `Gson` serialises instances of these generated beans such that only the `Map` entries are included in the resulting `JSON` string, and the explicitly-defined fields are ignored.

Here is a code snippet showing how I use `Gson` to serialise an object:

```
    private String serialize(Object obj) {
        return new Gson().toJson(obj);
    }
```

From debugging the serialisation path, I can see that `Gson` is selecting its internal `MapTypeAdapterFactory` to perform the serialization which, makes sense since only the Map entries end up in the JSON string.
Separately, if I serialize a bean that does NOT subclass HashMap, then `Gson` selects its internal `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` instead.

I think what I need is to implement my own custom type adapter that essentially combines the functionality of the `Reflective` and `Map` type adapter factories.
Does this sound like a good plan? Has anyone else done something similar to this and could perhaps provide an example to get me started? This will be my first foray into `Gson` custom type adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that by default `Gson` treats these objects like `Map` so we can use it to serialise all `key-value` pairs and manually serialise rest of them using [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html).

Simple serialiser implementation could look like below:

```
class MixedJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject json = serialiseAsMap(src, context);
        serialiseAsPojo(src, context, json);

        return json;
    }

    private JsonObject serialiseAsMap(Object src, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return (JsonObject) context.serialize(src, Map.class);
    }

    private void serialiseAsPojo(Object src, JsonSerializationContext context, JsonObject mapElement) {
        Method[] methods = ReflectionUtils.getAllDeclaredMethods(src.getClass());
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (shouldSerialise(method)) {
                final Object result = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, src);
                final String fieldName = getFieldName(method);
                mapElement.add(fieldName, context.serialize(result));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldSerialise(Method method) {
        final String name = method.getName();

        return method.getParameterCount() == 0 &&
                ReflectionUtils.USER_DECLARED_METHODS.matches(method) &&
                !IGNORED_METHODS.contains(name) &&
                (name.startsWith("is") || name.startsWith("get"));
    }

    private static final List<String> IGNORED_METHODS = Arrays.asList("isEmpty", "length"); //etc

    private String getFieldName(Method method) {
        final String field = method.getName().replaceAll("^(is|get)", "");

        return StringUtils.uncapitalize(field);
    }
}
```

The most complex part is find all `POJO` getters and invoke them on given object. I used [reflection `API`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html) from `Spring` library just for example. Below you can find example how to use it (I assume that all `POJO` classes extends `HashMap`):

```
import com.model.Foo;
import com.model.Pojo;
import com.model.Pojo1;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Pojo + Map: ");
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.put("character1", new Foo("Morty", 15));
        pojo.put("character2", new Foo("Rick", 60));

        System.out.println(serialize(pojo));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Map only: ");
        Pojo1 pojo1 = new Pojo1();
        pojo1.put("int1", 1);
        pojo1.put("int2", 22);
        System.out.println(serialize(pojo1));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Pojo only:");
        System.out.println(serialize(new Pojo()));
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static final Gson gson = createGson();

    private static Gson createGson() {
        MixedJsonSerializer adapter = new MixedJsonSerializer();
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                // in case you have many classes you need to use reflection
                // to register adapter for each needed class.
                .registerTypeAdapter(Pojo.class, adapter)
                .registerTypeAdapter(Pojo1.class, adapter)
                .create();
    }

    private static String serialize(Object obj) {
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Pojo + Map: 
{
  "character2": {
    "name": "Rick",
    "age": 60
  },
  "character1": {
    "name": "Morty",
    "age": 15
  },
  "prop1": "Value1",
  "ten": 10,
  "foo": {
    "name": "Test",
    "age": 123
  }
}

Map only: 
{
  "int2": 22,
  "int1": 1
}

Pojo only:
{
  "prop1": "Value1",
  "ten": 10,
  "foo": {
    "name": "Test",
    "age": 123
  }
}
```

If you have to many classes to register them manually you can use reflection to scan given packages and register serialiser for them. See: [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: @ZioberMichal, thanks for the example.  I'll give it a try.   One detail I left out  in trying to simplify things a bit is that all of these beans will actually subclass one of our common classes which subclasses HashMap<String, T>.  So, to avoid having to register every class, I think I'll try the TypeAdapterFactory approach since I can key off whether a particular class is an instance of our common super class (e.g. "DynamicModel<T>").   I also control the generation of these beans so I can generate the metadata (i.e. TypeToken) that represents the Map value type T.

Comment: @PhilAdams, your comment changes a little bit above question. If you control generation process maybe you can change that this root class extends `Map`. See [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). In case you will find some problems with implementing custom serialiser just update a question with new all info and maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: @ZioberMichal, in the end, I used your advice to use composition instead of inheritance.   All the generated dynamic models inherit from my DynamicModel<T> super class which contains a field of type Map<String, T> to store the arbitrary properties, plus each subclass defines 0 or more of their own fields.   I ended up implementing a TypeAdapterFactory which, more or less, combines the function from ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory and MapTypeAdapterFactory.   Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @PhilAdams, I'm glad I could help a little. I was also thinking about merging `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` and `MapTypeAdapterFactory` but this solution looked to me overcomplicated.